# How to add pageview event in react native

Tags: react-native, google-analytics

I am trying to add events for pageview which should be visible in Behavior -> Site Contant -> All Pages

Can anybody help me regading adding pageview events.
I am using react-native-google-analytics-bridge

Answer (score 0):

I use `react-ga` module for *google analytics*. I use `pageView` to add page views and you can call this function where you want in the app. To create event I use

```
ReactGA.event({
   category: 'Click',
   action: 'Button clicked',
   label: 'Button login clicked',
});
```

This is an example to track all the pages visited.

This is my `index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And my App component:

```
class App extends Component {

    state = {
        page: '',
        loaded: false,
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        const page = window.location.pathname + (window.location.search? window.location.search : "");
        if(!prevState.loaded) {
            ReactGA.initialize('UA-XXXXXXX-0', {
                debug: false,
                titleCase: false,
            });
            prevState.loaded = true;
        }
        if(prevState.page !== page) {
            ReactGA.pageview(page);
            prevState.page = page;
        }
        return prevState;
    }

    render() {
        const { history } = this.props;

        return (
            <Application />
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: I get this error  "Cant find variable: document ". I think problem is react-ga does not work in react-native.

Comment: I use this library https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga with react nativa and it works for me.

Comment: [Issue](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/321#issuecomment-443685932) is like a my problem